# How to detect when the click event is removed?

Tags: jquery, events

I'm generating a dynamic DOM object like this:

```
$('<div />')
    .append($('<img />').attr('src', 'blabla'))
    .click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('ok');
    })
    .appendTo('body');
```

Of course the code is much more complex. But after some time (some events (including some AJAX calls and DOM manipulation)), when I click on the `img` nothing is happening anymore. Somewhere in the code, something has removed the `click()` function!

I want to know *when*.

Is there a way do make a breakpoint / find / when there's a code that removes my "`click()`" handler?

Comment: Ar you creating `$('#mydiv')` dynamically too?

Comment: Yes I'm creating everything dynamically

Comment: `id` need to be unique per element. I hope you know that

Comment: Ok this is not a problem, I'm a little bit above beginner in JavaScript... i've modified my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said that you have created everything dynamically. (div and image both)

You need to separate `.click()` handler from `.append()`

```
$(document).on('click','img',function(){
   e.preventDefault();
   alert('ok');
});
```

This is called [jQuery event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

***A sample snippet:-***

```js
$('<div />').append($('<img />').attr('src', 'https://orig00.deviantart.net/0490/f/2016/193/8/a/icons_never_die__by_sinfulgurorose-da9rrty.png')).appendTo('body');

$(document).on('click','img',function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('ok');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note:- dynamically added element cannot be addressed by simple event handler. You have to use `.on()` for them

Comment: You've put me on the right track. The anwser should have been: "first add your element to the DOM then only **after** you can apply click() handler". But what is not normal is that the clic() handler was working *before any DOM modification*. Yes. My mates (3 developpers) are watching the problem and I'm not dreaming ^^.

Comment: @OlivierPons  glad to help you :):).

Comment: The problem is not about "Event Delegation" though... it's about "adding dynamically DOM"

Answer (score 0):

Use a class on `img` for event delegation like,

```
// this will bind click event on all images having class image only
$(document).on('click','img.image', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('ok');
});
```